# AWS RDS proxy performs bad with the read-only endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I have an AWS RDS aurora cluster with couple of read replicas. I am using an [RDS proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/improving-application-availability-with-amazon-rds-proxy/) instance for connecting to the database for high availability.

For testing the failover performance, I wrote a simple application that constantly ping the database in a loop. Then I trigger a database failover via aws-cli/web-console while the application is running. The application logs the time it took to recover the connection after a failed ping.

When compared with a direct connection to the aurora cluster writer endpont, RDS proxy writer endpoint consistently performs well. (my observations align with the results shown in the [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/improving-application-availability-with-amazon-rds-proxy/)).

However, when compared with a direct connection to the aurora cluster reader endpoint, RDS proxy read-only endpont performs badly. i.e. if you only need a read-only connection to the database, you shouldn't use the proxy, instead you should directly connect to the cluster reader endpoint.

After many tests I still see the same results. Can someone explain why it behaves like this ? is AWS RDS proxy only suitable for read-write database connections ?

Comment: Haven't personally encountered this but it's a great question if there's a way to confidently reproduce this (can you make the application and configuration opensource maybe?) +1